# Why do some Christians have trouble with the concept of non-existence?

Tags: death, resurrection, belief

Atheists have no trouble understanding that:

- When someone dies, their consciousness, personality, and self simply cease to exist.
- One day it *might* be possible to take a copy of someone's mind, store it digitally, and then recreate that person at a later date.
  (In SF stories, this is often used as a way of taking a backup just before someone takes part in a dangerous situation, just in case.)
- The question of *where* that consciousness would be while it isn't in use doesn't make sense.

On the other hand, many Christians have trouble accepting the concept of non-existence between death and resurrection.
They often reject it outright, insisting that neither permanent nor temporary non-existence is possible.

A concept, one that can easily be understood by atheists, can't be accepted as a reasonable possibility by people that are willing to accept almost any natural explanation an atheist would accept, plus accept supernatural explanations.

I'm not aware of any scripture saying that even temporary non-existence is impossible.

So, with respect to a non-existent state of death, what is the fundamental belief that separates those that think it *might be possible*, and those that *know it is impossible*?

Comment: This is a loaded question. It fallaciously presupposes that atheists, generally, understand what consciousness is. That's far from being the case, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_problem_of_consciousness

Comment: It's not that they can't understand. It's that they don't want to because it conflicts with their theologies.

Comment: "have trouble" makes it sound like a difficulty grasping the concept, but when you state "between death and resurrection" it sounds like more along why do they "reject" the concept. That's easier -- because it's not what Scripture teaches according to most Christian schools and it's also philosophically problematics

Comment: Future non-existence is not traditionally/biblically a part of the Christian hope.

Comment: "How do such Christians explain why a concept, which can easily be understood by atheists, can't be understood by people that are willing to accept almost any natural explanation an atheist would accept, plus accept supernatural explanations?" Why do you think Christians can't understand it? This question is like asking why most people "have trouble" with the concept of a flat earth.

Comment: @curiousdannii. A Google search for [conscious dead](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Achristianity.stackexchange.com+conscious+dead&oq=site%3Achristianity.stackexchange.com) on this site gets 525 results. Most of these are asking/arguing about whether the dead are conscious. It is hardly “like asking why most people “have trouble" with the concept of a flat earth”. Questions about *where* people are between death and resurrection indicate a lack of understanding of the concept of not being anywhere.

Comment: I'm not aware of any serious theologian stating that non-existence is *impossible*. God easily could annihilate a soul if He so chose. Most Christians think annihilationism is a heresy. That is, God *will not* annihilate a soul, not that He *cannot*. Furthermore, the setup for this question makes all sorts of philosophical assumptions (eg that the human mind can be wholly contained in a material body) about contentious philosophical questions without backing them up. If you want to know why annihilationism is generally considered heresy, I'd suggest removing the philosophical bias.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, we are of good courage, and we would rather be away from the body
> and at home with the Lord. (2 Corinthians 5:8)

> “Then they will go away to eternal punishment, but the righteous to
> eternal life.” (Matthew 25:46)

> 11 And this is the testimony: God has given us eternal life, and this
> life is in his Son. 12 Whoever has the Son has life; whoever does not
> have the Son of God does not have life. (1 John 5)

> 11 After he had said this, he went on to tell them, “Our friend
> Lazarus has fallen asleep; but I am going there to wake him up.”
>
> 12 His disciples replied, “Lord, if he sleeps, he will get better.” 13
> Jesus had been speaking of his death, but his disciples thought he
> meant natural sleep. (John 11:11-12)

From these and many other verses, Christians weave together their concept of death. The analogy of sleep does not match non-existence, but a different state of consciousness. The analogy of leaving this world to be with the Lord conveys a change of location. The idea of eternal life is one without interruption. And the fact that we who have faith already have that eternal life means that we do not wait for a future time after a period of non-existence to be remade. We have it already and so we expect no interruption in our life going forward.

Also, eternal punishment is not possible if the object of judgment is gone. So divine justice demands the eternal existence of the reprobate.

The preceding lays out the case for an eternal existence, but as for why we have trouble with the idea of non-existence, that is simple. Our heart shrinks back in terror from the idea of ending. It is part of being human. Job cried out to God for someone to walk with him to the grave and his most passionate prayer was that after he died, in his own flesh he would see God. "I know that my redeemer lives" is a confession of faith in a bodily resurrection. Job was righteous and knew God as a friend. The man knew what he needed and that is what he prayed for. Likewise, all who know God long to be with him forever. That is the eternity that God has set in our heart, as Solomon said in Ecclesiastes 3. That longing goes beyond words, doctrines, and religion.